# fb_graph or koala for interacting with facebook graph API v2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, koala-gem

What are the advantages or disadvantages of fb_graph versus koala when trying to interact with the facebook's graph API v2.0.

My app is rails 3 and I use omniauth to authenticate a user with facebook, but I'm looking for a solution to post to a user's wall and interact with facebook's API v2.0. I don't know which gem I should integrate right now.

Can someone please explain the pros and cons of each solution? Thank you very much